# Multiple Paho MQTT clients or only one that routes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mqtt, paho

I have a Spring-boot service that consumes messages from different device types via an MQTT server, of course each device type has its own message format. At the moment there are five types. Each one of them is handled by a separate component in the application. In total there are approximately 15 000 messages per second. The messages aren't spread even over the topics, one topic has 10 000 of them alone. I've tried to find some best practices and performance info around the Paho client but there isn't much out there.

How is the Paho client performing during high loads?
Should I stay with one Paho client that subscribes to all messages and then internally route them to correct consumers, or should I let each consumer component create its own client?

Right now I'm leaning towards the second option. More threads will be created but less code (no need to create routing etc) and better separation. But on the other hand there are multiple clients running.

[image]

Comment: Are there an news about this? Because, as you already mentioned, it is hard to find any best practices ...

Comment: Old story but yes we went with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I'm leaning towards the second option. More threads will be
>   created but less code (no need to create routing etc) and better
>   separation.

I agree, the 2nd approach is the best.  Always go with the KIS (Keep It Simple) principle.